# What are common or archaic nicknames for Michelangelo?

Tags: name, proper-nouns

In a few hours, I will most likely have a son. We're pretty sure we know his name, but we were thinking about nicknames. What are common nicknames *in Italy* for Michelangelo? I'd be interested in any of the following:

- Italy nicknames (modern or archaic) for Michelangelo
- Italy nicknames (modern or archaic) for Michele
- Italy nicknames (modern or archaic) for Angelo

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for. Michelangelo is so strongly associated with the famous artist that it cannot be replaced by a nickname.  Michele and Angelo, on the other hand, do not suggest Michelangelo as a name.

Comment: Congratulations for the future birth, what a happy Christmas!

Comment: @Gio There are also common people whose name is Michelangelo, usually shortened as Michele, the more modern Mik (pronounced as written) or other nicknames listed in Federico Poloni's answer.

Comment: @CarLaTeX - Angelo, Michele and all possible variants have little if nothing to do with Michelangelo. They are just common names or nicknames. I understand OP is looking for a nick which  suggests Michelangelo, but I don't think there is.

Comment: @Gio I don't agree

Comment: @CarLaTeX - Angelo and Michele are not nicks for Michelangelo, they are just common names. While Mick is a nick for Micheal, for instance.

Comment: @Gio Do you have a friend whose name is Michelangelo? How do you call him?

Comment: In my experience and considering some other comments and answers, I'd say that there is no “standard”, universally recognised nickname for Michelangelos. But why not coin one yourselves? Why looking for something that possibly doesn't even exist “in the wild”?

Comment: @CarLaTeX - you are missing the point here.

Comment: @DaG - mi sembra fosse chiamato "Michelagnolo" ai suoi tempi.

Comment: @Gio I think I'm catching the OP's point!

Comment: @Gio [Here](http://www.behindthename.com/name/michelangelo) they say that Michelangelo refers to archangel Michael (even if I don't know if the site is reliable).

Comment: @CarLaTeX - I think it is reliable, but ***there is no nickname***  for it. Incidentally, my father's name was "Arcangelo" (I'm not joking), and the shorthest nick he ever got was "'..cangelo" .... but also in that case, there is no nick for it.

Comment: We may call Pierfrancesco "Pierfi", or Giampaolo "Giampi", but Michelangelo .....

Comment: @Gio I think I miss the exact meaning of nickname, then! However, merry Christmas to you and your dad Arcangelo :) I think I would have called him Ange or Arca... In milanese Angelino is called 'ngiulin...

Comment: Many time a _double-name_ (Gian Luca) or a _composed-name_ (Gianluca) name in Italian is shortened choosing one between the two parts (Gianni or Luca in this case, more often Luca); so I think if to be shortened, it will finish in Angelo or Michele... or they will give a totally unrelated nick... In my experience there is no _official_ short-name or nickname for Michelangelo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both *Michele* and *Angelo* can be shortened to *Lino*, through *Michele*->*Michelino* (diminutive suffix) -> *Lino*.

In spoken Italian you may hear *Miche* / *Miché* and *Ange* (or *Michi* and *Angi*, but the *-i* suffix suggests more a feminine name in my view). Because of the strong English culture influence, I wouldn't be surprised to hear *Mike*, too (pronounced like in English).

For *Michelangelo*, only *Miche*, *Michi* and *Mike* sound usual to my ear.

Comment: For the very little it's worthy, most of these sound quite forced to me. Which is not to put in doubt Federico's experience; it's just that probably these forms are not usual in all of Italy.

Comment: To me *Miché* sounds a little bit southern (but Federico isn't from the south, so maybe it's just me). Probably where I'm from we would shorten *Michele* as *Lele* or *Michi*.

Comment: These are all fascinating answers! And, the child is now born! His name is Michelangelo but we are still trying to sort out a nickname. It generally sounds like all accepted nicknames are more tightly tied to Michele or Angelo. My family is Italian on both sides, but we are American, so we don't know much about how nicknames are used in modern Italy. We've asked my cousin but she hasn't replied yet. I may a post another question about nicknames in general. Thank you!

Comment: @LoftyGoals - Off topic: in my experience the best, or at least the longest-lived, nicknames are born spontaneously, from a mispronunciation by a child, from a joke, from an unexpected mental association, not conceived theoretically or found on a website.

Answer (score 4):

I have a friend named Michelangelo. His friends call him with the whole name, Michelangelo, even if it's a mouthful.

His aunt is the only one that calls him Angelo, but several people call him Michèle or Michè. His fiancée calls him Mìchi (or maybe it's Miki -- they're pronounced the same).

The whole family has lived in Florence for as long as anyone remembers.

As for the alternate spellings, in Italian the name was once either spelled *Michelangiolo* or *Michelagnolo*. Both *angiolo* and *agnolo* are archaic forms of *angelo* (angel), the latter conflated with *agnello* (lamb); in the *Decameron* (around 1350 CE) there's a novel referring to the *Agnolo Gabriello* (the Archangel Gabriel), and to this day some old stone street plaques near Piazzale Michelangelo in Florence (around 1850 CE) show the spelling *Michelangiolo*, which is also to be found in [many books from those years](https://books.google.it/books?id=9i03AAAAIAAJ&dq=alcune%20memorie%20di%20michelangelo%20buonarroti&hl=it&pg=PP5#v=onepage&q=alcune%20memorie%20di%20michelangelo%20buonarroti&f=false).